# speed up testing in PhoneGap

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

How to speed up testing on Android 4.0.3 with phoneGap and Eclipse? It is running so slow.... It needs one minute to run application, when the emulator is previously started.

Comment: Go for a better system... Probably a MAC :)

Answer (score 0):

It will run however quickly it possibly can.

What is the spec of your development machine.

You can tweak the memory given to a jvm but I doubt that will help you too much - if you wanna try : Making a new AVD and add a specific property : `Device RAM Size 1024`

That should significantly increase the speed of the emulator itself, if your machine can afford the memory!

Comment: Is it okay to run Android Emulator on Intel Atom(x86)?